# Learning to work with core pattern only

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to learn "core" patterns so I can start using them more often. Consider I am trying to solve the following problem.

`data = {2,{4,2,3},5,{7,3},{},4,1}` (assume `List` will not appear beyond level 1)

To get only non-list elements I can use the following pattern.

`data //. {x:___,{___},y:___}:>{x,y}`

Is there a way to do the same using a sub-pattern replacement (regular expressions allow that)

`data//.{___,t:{___},___}:>Nothing` (I want to only replace `t` with `Nothing`)

Next how do I get only list elements.

`data //. (...)`

Allowed functionality:

• Basic Pattern Objects

• Composite Patterns

• Restrictions on Patterns

• Pattern Defaults

<< Pattern Matching Functions are NOT allowed except for the following >>

• `Replace` (third argument `levelspec` NOT allowed)

• `ReplaceAll`

• `ReplaceRepeated`

Comment: It is of course a valid exercise but if you want to "start using them more often" then not using "Pattern Matching Functions" makes no sense.

Comment: These high level "Pattern Matching Functions" bypass the need to design composite patterns thus one never gets the chance to learn about core pattern constructs like `Shortest`, `Longest`, `PatternSequence`, `Except` etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89979/discussion-on-question-by-user13892-learning-to-work-with-core-pattern-only).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the artificial restrictions posed by the OP are unusual, and any effort will likely only benefit this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting this only because I can't resist pattern matching puzzles. I really don't think it's good question.

```
data = {2, {4, 2, 3}, 5, {7, 3}, {}, 4, 1};
```

Question 1

```
data //. m : {___, t : {___}, ___} :> (m /. t -> Nothing)
```

> `{2, 5, 4, 1}`

Question 2

```
List @@ ((tag @@ data) //. tag[x___, _Integer, y___] :> tag[x, y])
```

> `{{4, 2, 3}, {7, 3}, {}}`

I would never use such code. The sane way to make these list manipulations is

```
Cases[data, _Integer]
```

> `{2, 5, 4, 1}`

```
DeleteCases[data, _Integer]
```

> `{{4, 2, 3}, {7, 3}, {}}`

These are just a much pattern matching solutions as the silly answers I gave above. I don't buy into the concept that only the replace group of functions are true pattern matching functions.

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to select conditioned on being or not being a `List` then `Select` with `MatchQ` and `Except` with pattern `_List` is more appropriate.

```
Select[MatchQ@Except[_List]]@data
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 4, 1}
> ```

and

```
Select[MatchQ[_List]]@data
```

> ```
> {{4, 2, 3}, {7, 3}, {}}
> ```

However, if you must use replacement then `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) is not necessary for the conditions you describe (`ReplaceRepeated` can lead to infinite replacement when used incorrectly).  `Replace` at level 1 is sufficient.

```
Replace[data, _List -> Nothing, {1}]
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 4, 1}
> ```

and

```
Replace[data, Except[_List] -> Nothing, {1}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 2, 3}, {7, 3}, {}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For reasons unknown the OP imposed a bunch of arbitrary restrictions on the problem (such as not using the third argument to `Replace`)