# Design completion idea for Position

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language

This is not exactly a question but rather a suggestion for a design which I think would greatly improve Mathematica. Before I put this to Wolfram Research I would like to see what other people think about it. Since these days Wolfram is hosting many language design and consistency meeting, I think these might be good times to suggest language improvement ideas.

It is a suggestion for deeper integration of `Position` inside the pattern-matcher. Currently if you look at the `"guide/RulesAndPatterns"` page, `Position` is classified as a `Pattern Matching Function` like `Cases` rather than a `Pattern Construct Wrapper` like `Repeated`,`Except`,`Longest`,`...`.

Its current syntax, `Position[expr,pattern,levelspec,n]` is geared towards parsing the `expr` looking for `pattern` at a specified level `levelspec` for some number of matches `n`. It works independently from what is happening in its surrounding. This creates a limitation like if looking for the position of a `subPattern` which matches in `expr` while matching a `pattern`, the only way to achieve this currently is by invoking the pattern-matcher twice.

- Firstly when the main `pattern` is matched in `expr` to get the position of the `parts` in `expr` matching the `pattern`.
- Secondly when `subPattern` are matched in `parts` to get the position of `subParts` in `parts` matching the `subPattern`. But the `subPattern` could exist in multiple position so tagging is needed to refer to the correct `subPart`.

See: [Can someone please explain the code from another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192124/can-someone-please-explain-the-code-from-another-question) (Answer by Leonid Shifrin)

One stupid question I asked earlier also highlight this fact.

See: [Learning to work with core pattern only](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191878/learning-to-work-with-core-pattern-only) (Closed)

Given a `data` like `data = {2,{4,2,3},5,{7,3},{},4,1}`. One way to differentiate the outer `List` from the inner `List` for the pattern-matcher is to tag it with another `Head`.

`List @@ ((tag @@ data) //. tag[x___, _Integer, y___] :> tag[x, y])`

Because currently the pattern-matcher is blind in the sense that it has no awareness of its `Position` when it is crawling the expression to match pattern.

Admittedly since the expression tree is opened down to `Leaves`. The pattern-matcher still has awareness of the `Depth` of the currently reached `subExpr` even though it can't look up to see the `Position` of `subExpr` within the `expr`. So this problem could be solved by

`data//.{t:{x___,_Integer,y___}/;Depth[t]==3:>{x,y}}`

without the need for tagging. Another way could be to forcefully change the expression by

```
data={2,{4,2,3},5,{7,3},{},4,1}
Do[
Print[data=data/.{(t:{x___,_Integer,y___}/;(Echo[Position[data,t],"position"]=={{}})):>{x,y}}],
{k,5}]
```

But this is still not a "natural" way.

Rather than having a whole suite of functions, like `Position[expr, pattern]` or `SubPosition[expr, pattern, subPattern]`, it would be a nicer interface to make `Position[]` a pattern wrapper rather than a pattern matching function.

`Position` should be a pattern wrapper that tells the pattern-matcher that the `name` in `Pattern[name, ...]` wherever referred as `Position[name]` points to the (matched) object's location rather than the (matched) object itself.

So the above should be solved like:

`data//.{t:{x___,_Integer,y___}/;Position[t]=={}:>{x,y}}`

and old functionality of `Position` like

`Position[data,{_,_}]`

could be replaced by

`Cases[data,t:{_,_}:>Position[t]]`.

With this new wrapper behavior of `Position`, one could solve the `SubPosition` problem by simply:

`Cases[expr,pattern:>Position[subPattern],\[Infinity]]`.

Do you think this is a good way to improve (or rather expose) the positional awareness of the pattern-matcher?

Note: `Position` could be kept as it is for backward compatibility but the new behavior could be linked to a new symbol, say `Location` or `Pointer`.

Comment: "Note: Position could be kept as it is for compatibility but the new behavior could be linked to a new symbol, say Location or Pointer." So this is an entirely new feature and not at all related to `Position` or to what `Position` is supposed to do...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I would rather want the `Position` to have the new behavior and completely scrap the current one. Since the new behavior can do the work of the current one but the current one cannot do the work of this new behavior. But I highly doubt it could be done without breaking a lot of code since `Position` is an elementary function which was introduced back in version 1.0

Comment: "But I highly doubt it could be done without breaking a lot of code since Position is an elementary function" That's also what I thought. This is why I believe (and hope!) that this inquiry will be ignored by WRI...

Comment: Why not make up your own function (call it Location or Subposition or something) that implements your desired functionality? This way everyone can see how useful it would be.

Comment: To temper things a bit, maybe consider writing an example implementation of your idea, and maybe try submitting it to the [Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/)? (That being said, I don't see here a question that is suitable for SE's format, but will defer closing decisions to other people.)